# My Boss birthday gift - Retailer Probability

Tags: probability

Im struggling to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated:
My boss's birthday is 5 days away and I haven’t yet ordered the book I wanted to gift her. There are 4 online retailers (A, B, C & D) that promise to deliver the book within the 5 days, if I place an order right away. However, I don’t trust them. I estimate from reviews available online, that the probabilities of A, B, C & D delivering on time are 0.5, 0.8, 0.6 and 0.9 respectively. Playing safe, I ordered the book from all four retailers. What is the probability that I am able to give my boss the gift on her birthday? (Make the reasonable assumption that the retailers don’t consult each other.)

Select one:

```
a. 0.78
b. 0.004
c. 0.9
d. 0.996
```

Comment: It feels as if you're asking us to do your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the probability that all of them do not deliver on time.

$p=(1-0.9)(1-0.8)(1-0.6)(1-0.5)=0.004$

Hence, the probability that at least one of them delivers on time is:

$1-p=0.996$